# How do I highlight, and then copy and paste a whole block of code in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am entirely new to vim and I ran into the problem of not being able to select and copy a large chunk of code and paste it elsewhere, like what I used to do on Visual C++.

Comment: If you are very new to vim, try running `vimtutor` in your shell. It will take you about half an hour or something, but it will teach you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>v</kbd> to select, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode.

Press <kbd>d</kbd> to cut or <kbd>y</kbd> to copy. Move the cursor, and press <kbd>P</kbd> to paste before the cursor, or <kbd>p</kbd> to paste after the cursor.